# How can I validate a Wordpress Theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-thesis-theme

I am building a WordPress theme and my theme got Rejection form Market Place (Themforest). Because, my theme was not able to pass Validator issues.

I am trying to validate my theme at https://validator.w3.org/ and I get some validation error because WordPress itself generates lots of invalid HTML Tags.

So, I would like to learn How can I validate my WordPress Theme? I would like to get some help for the same.

Comment: Stop down voting others and let know what are you looking for in real. Its  not a timepass site

Comment: User @Vishal posted 5 questions till now and all are downvoted. Please, read the rules of Stackoverflow before asking any question if you are not clear what to ask for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Validating the markup of your theme is the process of ensuring that the web pages conform to web standards defined by various organizations. These standards ensure web pages are interpreted in the same way by different browsers, search engines, and other web clients.

Conforming to standards and regulations is one of many ways you can make your theme universally understood. Make sure your code and styles validate across the board. That means they have to meet the standards set by the W3C Organization and pass a variety of validations for CSS and XHTML.

Not all validators check for the same things. Some only check CSS, others XHTML, and others for accessibility. If you are sincere in presenting standardized pages to the public, test them with several validators. The World Wide Web Consortium sets the standards and also hosts a variety of web page validators.
Validation Techniques #Validation Techniques

Validating your WordPress site means more than just checking the front page for errors. A theme’s template files are loaded in a modular fashion. While you may fix all the errors associated with the index.php and sidebar.php on your front page, errors may still exist within other template files such as single.php, page.php, archives.php, or category.php. Validate pages that load each of your theme template files.

The Your WordPress section in the WordPress Forums is dedicated to helping WordPress users in getting feedback about their sites. WordPress volunteers will do that for you for free. Be sure and read the WordPress Site Reviews Guidelines.

Comment: Here you can get more help about the same: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/validating-your-theme/

Comment: It is suggested to go through help document provided by related marketplace i.e, Themeforest code submission guidelines. Theme needs to be in perfection condition in order to get submited.